# How to prepopopulate Room database if there is already existing instance of it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want my users to be able to save room database on google drive and then load it from it on another device, first part is already implemented but I'm struggling with populating room database with new file.

This is my singleton of database:

```
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppRoomDataBase? = null
    fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppRoomDataBase {
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance != null) {
            return tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppRoomDataBase::class.java,
                "product_database"
            ).build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

And then when user wants to load database from google drive :

```
 private fun loadFileFromDrive() {
    val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "product_database")
    mDriveServiceHelper.queryFiles().addOnSuccessListener { fileList ->
       val database = fileList.files.first()
        mDriveServiceHelper.downloadFile(file,database.id)?.addOnSuccessListener {
                prepopulateRoomDatabaseWithFile(file)
        }
    }
}


private fun prepopulateRoomDatabaseWithFile(file : File){
    Room.databaseBuilder(application,AppRoomDataBase::class.java,"product_database")
        .createFromFile(file)
        .build()
}
```

But it doesn't work, there is only documentation about how to create database initially from a file but I can't find anything about how to override current Room database with a new one only when it's needed , is It possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried MikeT solution but it is not working because I have many different places that I use ROOM database and in each of them I would have to pass an information that there is new database that should be used.

The better solution for my case is to just switch files of database by deleting previous one and moving dowloaded one to the directory of old one like this :

```
private fun swapDatabaseFiles(file: File){
    AppRoomDataBase.getDatabase(applicationContext).close()
    databaseFile.delete()
    copyFile(file.absolutePath,databaseFile.name,databaseFile.absolutePath)
    prepopulateRoomDatabaseWithFile(file)  // TO OPEN DATABASE
    val mainActivity = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)  // NOW RESTARTING ACTIVITY SO DATABASE IS REFRESHED
    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    startActivity(mainActivity)
}



 private fun copyFile(inputPath: String, inputFileName: String, outputPath: String) {
    var inputStream: InputStream?
    var out: OutputStream?
    try {
        inputStream = FileInputStream(inputPath)
        out = FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFileName)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var read: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
        inputStream.close()
        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        out.flush()
        out.close()
    } catch (fnfe1: FileNotFoundException) {
        fnfe1.message?.let { Log.e("tag fnfe1", it)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("tag exception", e.message!!)
    }
}
```

swap database function inside singleton of database :

```
fun swapDatabase(context: Context,file : File){
            INSTANCE?.close()
            INSTANCE = null
            synchronized(this){
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,AppRoomDataBase::class.java,"product_database")
                .createFromFile(file)
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
        }
        }
```

Edit : Refactored code and fixed error exception. Now works just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to close the original database and then build the second database setting INSTANCE.

The following is an example (only tested by closing the and then re-opening the single database, *see example below*).

```
@Database(entities = [UserEntity::class],version = 1)
abstract class UserDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: UserDatabase? = null
        private val DBNAME = "user.db"
        fun getInstance(context: Context, dbName: String = DBNAME): UserDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        UserDatabase::class.java,
                        dbName
                    ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                }
                return instance as UserDatabase
            }
            return instance as UserDatabase
        }
        fun swapDatabase(context: Context, databaseFile: File): UserDatabase {
            // If we need to swap then (instance is not null) close the database if it is open
            if (instance != null) {
                if (instance!!.isOpen) {
                    instance!!.close() // should commit database
                    instance == null
                }
            }
            // instance should now be null and the original database closed
            val dbpath = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME) // just showing how to get path where database should exist
            //copy database here from file
            return getInstance(context, dbpath.name) // note in theory a different file name (database file name) could be used 
        }
    }
}
```

- Note for convenience and brevity .allowMainThreadQueries has been used.

**Example**

The following example utilises the above (albeit to swap the SAME database) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: UserDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = UserDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getDao()
        dao.insertOneUser(UserEntity(0L,"UserFred","Fred@email.com","Fred","Bloggs","password"))
        for(u: UserEntity in dao.getAllUsers()) {
            Log.d("USERINFODB1","UserId = ${u.userid} UserName = ${u.userName}")
        }
        // SWAP THE DATABASE (in this case to the same database)
        db = UserDatabase.swapDatabase(this,this.getDatabasePath("xxx"))
        for(u: UserEntity in dao.getAllUsers()) {
            Log.d("USERINFODB2","UserId = ${u.userid} UserName = ${u.userName}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run the log includes:-

```
D/USERINFODB1: UserId = 0 UserName = UserFred
D/USERINFODB2: UserId = 0 UserName = UserFred
```

Comment: Your solution would be right but not in my case, first of all if You would use different database You would see it doesn't work cause dao hasn't got updated, second of all with this approach I would need to store referencee to new database in every place that I use it.